Unifying NavigationView's Pane and Content Background color
This is what the program looks like after I implemented the x:Key into it. It's almost perfect, I just can't figure out how to make the NavigationPane's expanded form have no background on it, I need it to be transparent because I am overlaying a gradient for the background of the app. If you review the code below you can see I tried using the NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground key to try and set the opacity and background, but I got no luck as no difference was made.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<winex:WindowEx
    xmlns:winex="using:WinUIEx"
    Width="800"
    Height="500"
    MinHeight="500"
    MinWidth="800"
    x:Class="Hostware.Hostware"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Hostware"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Background="Orange">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <!--<AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{x:Bind nvSample2.CompactModeThresholdWidth}" /> -->
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="sidebar.PaneDisplayMode" Value="LeftCompact"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <!-- For the top nav collapsing to left hamburger sample -->
        

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <NavigationView
                x:Name="sidebar"
                
                Grid.Row="1" Height="485"
                Header="This is Header Text"
                Margin="0" PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                IsTabStop="False" AlwaysShowHeader="False"
                Background="Orange"
                SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged2"
                OpenPaneLength="150"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                IsPaneOpen="True"
                Canvas.ZIndex="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                IsTitleBarAutoPaddingEnabled="True"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed">
                <NavigationView.Resources>
                    <!-- This top margin is the height of the custom titleBar -->
                    <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentMargin">0,48,0,0</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewMinimalContentMargin">0,48,0,0</Thickness>
                    <Thickness x:Key="NavigationViewContentGridBorderThickness">1,1,0,0</Thickness>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewContentBackground" Color="Transparent" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" Opacity="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                  
                    
                    <!-- This is the rounded corner on the Top left of the L Pattern -->
                    <CornerRadius x:Key="NavigationViewContentGridCornerRadius">8,8,8,8</CornerRadius>
                </NavigationView.Resources>

                
                <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1">
                        <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                            <ImageIcon Source="\Assets\icon_tf.png"></ImageIcon>
                        </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                    </NavigationViewItem>
                        <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item2" Tag="SamplePage2" Icon="Save" />
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" Icon="Refresh" />
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" Icon="Download" />
                </NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <!--<NavigationView.Content> -->
                    <Frame Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="contentFrame5" Background="white" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <!--</NavigationView.Content> -->
            </NavigationView>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</winex:WindowEx>


You can override the NavigationViewContentBackground resource which is used for the Content's Background.
You might also need to override the NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground resource if the PlaneDisplayMode is LeftCompact or LeftMinimal.
<NavigationView
    PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
    Background="Orange">
    <NavigationView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
            Color="Orange" />
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="NavigationViewContentBackground"
            Color="Transparent" />
    </NavigationView.Resources>
</NavigationView>

You can learn about this in the generic.xaml file.

thanks, is there any wiki somewhere where I can find all the "x:Key(s)"? I don't see them on the microsoft learn page.

Unfortunately no. That's why I added the link to the generic.xaml file.

is there a key that I can use to make the expanded pane background transparent with no blurred color? I tried setting NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground to transparent but no luck.

AFAIK, the background color you set to the NavigationView is not blurred. The code in my answer should render the NavigationView's pane and content with the same orange color.

yeah, it renders the content transparent, and the pane is the same color when it's closed, but when I expand it it turns, a slightly transparent black, the code works fine to make the content transparent, but you seemed good with the topic and I was also stuck on this so I thought you might know what to do to fix it. I attached a new screenshot so you could see what I'm talking about.

I updated the code in my answer. You need to set the NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground.

Oh wow, it works, thanks for all your help, that's all I need. Have a good day :)
